# Find the integral of $P(X<Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let X,Y be r.v following a normal distribution ($\mu_X,\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_X^2,\sigma_Y^2 >0$) that are independent. Let $z:=X-Y$. What integral shows $P(X<Y)$. Do not compute it

I can not find the integral but I am fairly sure on how to compute it. What is the integral? Is it just the integral of the normal distribution from $\pm \infty$? I know the linear property applies for $Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply calculate $P(Z<0)$

$$Z\sim N(\mu_X-\mu_Y;\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)$$

To calculate it you need the tables but you can express it in terms of $\Phi$

---

The text gives you an important hint: find the distribution of $Z=X-Y$

As per mean and variance properties:

$$E(aX+bY)=aE(X)+bE(Y)$$

$$V(aX+bY)=a^2V(X)+b^2V(Y)$$

and for gaussian's properties $Z$ has the distribution I showed you thus

$$\mathbb{P}[Z<0]=\int_{-\infty}^0 f_Z(z)dz=\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_Y-\mu_X}{\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}}\right)$$

Comment: What bounds would I need? In the integral that is

Comment: And by symmetry would't the $\sigma$'s get subtracted?

Comment: That is, both the mean and variance.*

Comment: @mathstudent23 : I added all the details in my edits.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the fact that it would equal the cdf times that part. Is that a theorem? The transformation one?

Comment: @mathstudent23: it is not a $\times$ its the CDF of a Standard gaussian evaluated in that argument. Aren't you familiar with Gaussian standarization?

Comment: No actually not. I am in an introductory course haivng covered discrete and now onto continuous r.v where I have just begun to use the normal distribution. I only know about the properties for mean, variance and a arbitrary constant added onto the r.v. I also know the symmetry property but thats about it. (of course I know CDF and PDF etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is useful for you a numerical example:

Let $X\sim N(1;1)$ and $Y\sim N(2;1)$ and let's $X,Y$ independent.

We want to calculate $P(X<Y)=P(X-Y<0)$

To do that we first derive $f_Z(z)$.

As per what I told you in my previous post, $Z\sim N(-1;2)$

Thus

$$P(Z<0)=\Phi\left(\frac{0-(-1)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=76.025\%$$

Comment: I follow all the way to the actually calculation where I then am not following. So I see that $\Phi$ is the CDF (so the integral of $\pm \infty$ of $f_Z$) but what made you get to the argument (i.e the fraction)?.

Comment: @mathstudent23 : $\Phi$ is not the CDF of Z. The integral of Z cannot be calculated unless you pass through $\Phi$ that is the CDF of the Standard gaussian that is $N(0;1)$. Perhaps these are objects that you will study later

Comment: Ok I had to google $\Phi$ in probability where I got that it denotes"standard normal CDF". But then it would be impossible for me to answer this question since I cant use results I do not know.  Unless I am missunderstanding your approach.

Comment: @mathstudent23 :see my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok: Now that I know your background it is easier for me to help you...

Observe that your exercise explicitly states

> What integral shows P(X<Y)? Do not compute it

thus  what they want from you is this

$$\mathbb{P}[X<Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)}}e^{-[z-(\mu_X-\mu_Y)]^2/[2(\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)]} dz$$

...and nothing else.

Comment: Okay and the bounds are since that Z:=X-Y right?